# HTML Editor in Shiny

Tags: html, r, shiny

I am trying to add an html editor in my shiny app.

It is easy to convert html codes inside a textbox to html document via `renderUI()` function in shiny like ;

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    textInput("html_data","HTML INPUT"),
    uiOutput("result")
  )

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {


    output$result <- renderUI({
      HTML(paste0("<div>",input$html_data,"</div>"))
    })

})

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

However,I want to give a chance to the users who do not know coding html for creating their own html pages. So a simple textinput isn't enough. It must include ; Bold(B), Italic(I), Alignment parts etc. like a usual editor.

Are there any packages or open source codes to solve this? or Should it be done manually via assigning functions to the buttons created in shiny?

Comment: Perhaps https://thedubworld.wordpress.com/2016/03/13/adding-a-html-editor-to-shiny/

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [shinyAce](https://github.com/trestletech/shinyAce) package. It contains shiny wrappers for the [ace editor](https://ace.c9.io/) and supports syntax highlighting for different languages as well as code completion. A live demo can be found [here](https://starkingdom.shinyapps.io/shinyAce-01-basic/).